# Need help with this question.

Tags: definite-integrals

[image] I was trying to solve this question but got stuck. If we further solve it we get $I'(e)=0 $ which does no help to find the value of the integral. I know an alternate way to take $7$ as variable but I want to know if the process I used can help in anyway to evaluate this integral. How will we find $I(e)$ if $I'(e)$ comes 0 here? To be more clear I want to know how to evaluate this question using *Leibnitz rule* and differentiating with respect to $e$. I finally got $ I(e)=0+c$
Further I tried to find $ I(1) $ and I found it's giving 0 that would imply my $ c=0 $ that means answer should be $0$ but it's $ ln7 $. Please correct me where am I wrong.

Comment: Its not good to downvote without mentioning reason.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Double Integration**

Let $\displaystyle I = \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-7x}}{x}dx = \int^{\infty}_{0}\bigg(\int^{7}_{1}e^{-tx}dt\bigg)dx$

So $\displaystyle I = \int^{7}_{1}\bigg(\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-xt}dx\bigg)dt = \int^{7}_{1}\frac{1}{t}dt=\ln(t)\bigg|^{7}_{1} = \ln(7).$

**Using Differentiation under integral sign**

Let $\displaystyle I(\alpha) = \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{e^{-\alpha x}-e^{-x}}{x}dx,$ Then $\displaystyle I'(\alpha) = -\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x\cdot e^{-\alpha x}}{x}dx = -\frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{\alpha}\bigg|^{\infty}_{0}=\frac{1}{\alpha}$

So $\displaystyle I (\alpha) = \ln(\alpha)+\mathcal{C}.$ Put $\alpha =1,$ We get $I(1)=0$

So we gave $\displaystyle I (\alpha) = \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{e^{-\alpha x}-e^{-x}}{x}dx= \ln(\alpha).$

So $\displaystyle I(7)=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{e^{-7x}-e^{-x}}{x}dx = \ln(7).$

Comment: I know this as I have already mentioned. I just want to know if it's possible to further find the value the way I was evaluating.

Comment: I did not understand how you can differentiate w r to $e$, because $e$ is constant.

Comment: I wanted to use Leibnitz rule taking e as constant

Comment: @durgesh she means take e as some variable t so that integral is $I(t)$ and find $I'(t)$